# Como saber si un documento PDF esta firmado digitalmente en php?

Tags: php, pdf, firma-digital

Leí en un foro de aquí que buscando el string "adbe.pkcs7.detached" dentro del contenido del PDF funcionaba. Y si funciona pero en algunos casos, otros no. Alguien sabe de una solución más certera.

```
<?php
//from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9059073/284932
    function isStringInFile($file,$string){

    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    $valid = false; // init as false
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if (strpos($buffer, $string) !== false) {
            $valid = TRUE;
            break; // Once you find the string, you should break out the loop.
        }      
    }
    fclose($handle);

    return $valid;

}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// $data y $signature contienen los datos y la firma

// fetch la clave pública del certificado and ready it

$pubkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_public("file://src/openssl-0.9.6/demos/sign/cert.pem");

// Indica si la firma está bien o no.

$ok = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $pubkeyid);
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "Bien";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "Mal";
} else {
    echo "Error, comprobando firma...";
}

// Libera la clave de la memoria.

openssl_free_key($pubkeyid);
?>
```

Para más ejemplos y explicaciones consulta en la documentación oficial de PHP: [openssl-verify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php)